# Is this line safe from XSS in Laravel Blade templates

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Is this safe or not? 
Used in balde templating on Laravel

```
{!! ($user->first_name ? ' value="' . e($user->first_name) . '"' : '') !!}
```

I escape the one I output but should I also escape the one checked?

Thanks!

Comment: If you use bindings, it's safe. If you don't, it's not. Basically, this is it.

Comment: Thanks. How do they make it safe? Not sure to understand how bindings help. The $user->first_name  will come from the DB

Comment: The injection happens mainly if you use user input directly in DB query.  Any modification to user input, or data validation to input, use of bindings, etc can be used to avoid injection.

Comment: http://breakthesecurity.cysecurity.org/2010/12/hacking-website-using-sql-injection-step-by-step-guide.html look at this link, where normal injection tries

Comment: I see so why escape datas in the views?

Comment: This has nothing to do with binding since this is a template, so presumably the data has already been saved and so successfully escaped at the db-level. At the view level, assuming the `e()` function is to escape the data then you should be fine. No XSS attack is possible.

Comment: @commandantp you escape data in views so that users can't set their firstname to something like `<script>alert("I'm in ur browzer, breaking ur stuffs")</script>`. Escaping would turn that into `&lt;script&gt;alert(...`, effectively neutralizing [XSS injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: There is unlikely to be a SQL injection issue here because this code isn't creating SQL. There may be other kinds of security issue in the code you quoted, but not SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL injection is an input problem, not an output problem. Escaping output is to help avoid XSS issues. In this case, you're fine, but just to tidy up your code a little:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="{{ $user->first_name }}" />
```

If first_name is empty, value will be empty. If first name is populated, value will be the escaped output.

### Edit

*responding to comment*

Tidy code. Not tested, but this should only error if `$user` is not an object (or `$user->first_name` is a value that could not be implicitly converted to a string, like an array).

```
<input class="form-control width-50" required type="text" name="first_name" value="{{ !is_null(old('first_name')) ? old('first_name') : $user->first_name }}">
```

Comment: If they *really* care about not having the `value=""` there, then `@if($user->first_name) value="{{ $user->first_name }}" @endif` would also do it.

Comment: Thanks. That actually was an extract of that: ``<input class="form-control width-50" required type="text" name="first_name" {!! (old('first_name')) ? ' value="' . e(old('first_name')) . '"' : ($user->first_name ? ' value="' . e($user->first_name) . '"' : '') !!}>``  Don't know if I can tidy that - I think it crashes when $user->first_name is empty